# SASS List Not Working

Tags: function, sass, each, mixins

I am trying to make a SASS list working but its giving me issue. Can any of you please guide me what I am doing wrong and show the solution?

```
$colors: #02ce53, #05d297, #10cbc2, #e45042, #fe7e10, #01a2f0 
@each $color in $colors
    p
        color: $color
```

My generated CSS looks like:

```
p {
  color: #02ce53; }

p {
  color: #05d297; }

p {
  color: #10cbc2; }

p {
  color: #e45042; }

p {
  color: #fe7e10; }

p {
  color: #01a2f0; }
```

I actually want each p tag to have the color based on color sequence mentioned in the SASS list. How can I have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can get the index of your list with `index($list,$value)` inside `@each` directive and use it as `nth-child` index:

```
$colors: #02ce53, #05d297, #10cbc2, #e45042, #fe7e10, #01a2f0

@each $color in $colors
  p:nth-child(#{index($colors, $color)})
    color: $color
```

This gives you the following:

```
p:nth-child(1) {
  color: #02ce53;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
  color: #05d297;
}

p:nth-child(3) {
  color: #10cbc2;
}

p:nth-child(4) {
  color: #e45042;
}

p:nth-child(5) {
  color: #fe7e10;
}

p:nth-child(6) {
  color: #01a2f0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, list is now working but exactly not how I want it to be.

Generated, CSS is like:
p {
  color: #02ce53; }

p {
  color: #05d297; }

p {
  color: #10cbc2; }

p {
  color: #e45042; }

p {
  color: #fe7e10; }

p {
  color: #01a2f0; }

But as you can understand, I want nth child of p tag to have the color of nth color...... Please help

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. Now I get your point. I edit my original answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the issue :)

By the way, is it possible to determine number of children of any container using any SASS function?

Comment: Well, in SASS there are lists. You can use the length($list) list function. You can use it if you want to use “@for” instead of “@each” directive ( for example: “@for $i from 1 through length($list)” ).

Comment: Can you please help me find an answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895004/is-it-possible-to-determine-number-of-children-of-any-container-using-any-sass-f/47895089?noredirect=1#comment82757637_47895089

Comment: Done, hope it helps, although it is not a SASS-only solution.